[Security:090219]Error decrypting Secret Key java.lang.SecurityException: Crypto-J is disabled, a self-integrity check failed
I have the following error message when trying to import the domain configured for my weblogic 12.1.1 server from Eclipse version 2020-06
The server is invalid. Error occurred reading server credential. If the domain was recreated, the server instance in Eclipse must also be recreated. weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: [Security:090219]Error decrypting Secret Key java.lang.SecurityException: Crypto-J is disabled, a self-integrity check failed.
enter image description here
I have tried changing my version of Java to 1.6 and 1.7 without being able to import the domain that I should use in my application.
